# How to add multiple images using browse button

Tags: php, image-uploading

I have a following code where I can upload a single image. This image gets stored in both database and folder. Now what I want is to add multiple images. How can I do that. Help me to come out of this.

```
        <?php
            $uploadDir ="C:/wamp/www/dragongym/customers/";
                if(isset($_POST['submit']))
                {
                    $intime =DATE("H:i", STRTOTIME($_POST['intime']));
                    $outtime =DATE("H:i", STRTOTIME($_POST['outtime']));

                    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
                     $today         =   date("Y-m-d");
                    $msg="";
                    $res = "SELECT customer_id FROM customer ORDER by customer_id DESC LIMIT 1";
                    $qur = mysql_query($res);

                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qur, MYSQL_BOTH))
                    {
                        $last_id = $row['customer_id'];
                        $plus_id = 1;
                    }

                    if( $last_id !="")
                    {
                        $cust_id = $last_id + $plus_id;
                    }

                    $filePath="";
                    if($_FILES['cimage']['size'] > 0)
                    {
                        //  echo $cust_id;

                        // Temporary file name stored on the server for pdf
                        $filename  = basename($_FILES['cimage']['name']);
                        $extension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                        $new       = $cust_id.'.'.$extension;
                        $tmpName1  = $_FILES['cimage']['tmp_name'];
                        $fileSize = $_FILES['cimage']['size'];
                        $fileType = $_FILES['cimage']['type']; 

                        $filePath = $uploadDir . $new;

                        $resultes = move_uploaded_file($tmpName1, $filePath);
                        if (!$resultes)
                        {
                            echo "Error uploading file";
                            exit;
                        }

                        if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
                        {
                            $new = addslashes($new);
                            $filePath = addslashes($filePath);
                        }
                    }

                    $sql = 'INSERT INTO customer(customer_name,roll_no,customer_number,customer_address,tariff_id,intime,outtime,customer_image,active,joining_date) VALUES("'.$_POST['name'].'","'.$_POST['roll'].'","'.$_POST['number'].'","'.$_POST['address'].'","'.$_POST['tariff'].'","'.$intime.'","'.$outtime.'","'.$filePath.'","1","'.$today.'")';
                    $msg="<p style=\"color:#99CC00; font-size:13px;\"> Successfully!</p>";
                    if (!mysql_query($sql, $link))
                             {
                                     die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
                             }


        }
        ?>

        <form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h2>Registration Form</h2><?php echo $msg; ?>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="name" id="name" required class="txtfield">
        <label>Roll Number</label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="roll" id="roll" required class="txtfield">
        <label>Mobile Number</label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="number" required class="txtfield" id="mobnum">
        <label>Address</label>
        <textarea name="address" class="txtfield"></textarea>

        <label>Upload Photo</label>
        <input type="file" value="" name="cimage" class="txtfield">
        <!-- <label style="display: block">Timing</label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="intime" placeholder="Intime" required class="timefield timepicker">
        <input type="text" value="" name="outtime" placeholder="Outtime" required class="timefield timepicker">-->
        <input type="submit" value="Save" name="submit" class="btn buttonside1">                    
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery plugin for that.. 
there is lots of plugin available on google..try this one http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: The link works fine. But I want to store it in Database so that i would retrieve images for future use.

Answer (score 0):

to do multiple file upload you should first have multiple="true" in your tab like so

```
<input type="file" name='files[]' multiple='true'/>
```

then use foreach loop to upload files.

Comment: I have tried for loop. But it is omitting error. How to add for loop for the above code

Comment: have you used enctype ="multipart/form-data" ? as attribute in your form?

Comment: I have not used the for loop. @ sheroz

Comment: for multiple file upload you have to use foreach loop and do our file uploading and insertion in database in that loop

Comment: if i was helpful please rate :)